# SFTP prevent user from deleting original directory

Tags: linux, file-permissions, sftp, chroot, centos-8

I cannot find how to prevent chroot users from deleting some original directory. I have an SFTP that is already working. Below is my process to create a directory for new partners.

```
[root@...]# groupadd Orange
[root@...]# useradd -g Orange -d /SRV_PROD/Orange/ -s /sbin/nologin user_Orange
[root@...]# mkdir Orange/in
[root@...]# mkdir Orange/in/archives
[root@...]# mkdir Orange/out
[root@...]# mkdir Orange/out/archives
[root@...]# chown -R root:Orange Orange/
[root@...]# chown -R user_Orange:Orange Orange/out/
[root@...]# chown -R user_Orange:Orange Orange/in/
```

So everything is working as we expected, but users from group Orange can delete the directory archives.

How to avoid that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Are you asking how to stop deleting in/ and out/ or the contents in in/ and out/ ?  Do members of Orange need to be able to write filea or only read them?

Comment: Hello Davidgo. I am wonder how to not deleting the directory archives. Yes member of orange are able to write inside in and inside archives. Members of orange can write and delete files and directories they created. But not the directories I created to set up their access(in/archives , out/archives).